# Warning when flutter build apk command entered

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, dart-null-safety

When I run `Flutter build apk` command the terminal gives me a warning. But apk file generated successfully. Do you have any idea to how to solve this warning?
Here is my terminal output:

```
 Building with sound null safety
    
    Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
    Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01    
    Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
    Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          103.1s
    √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (16.3MB).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the Android Gradle Plugin version from 4.1.0 to 7.0.2 using new android
[image]

Comment: Is there a method to upgrade the gradle  plugin for every projects at once instead of upgrading one by one for every project?